# Is there an IDE for Ubuntu that combines Python, Gtk and Glade in one unique program?

Tags: python, gui, ide

I like PyCharm, but it doesn't have a GUI designer. I like the quickly package but I don't want to use Gedit as my editor. I tryed Ubuntu SDK but it's kind of hard to use python on it, and it's not Gtk. What I need is something like a MonoDenvelop for Python, with a pycharm look.

Does this exist? Is there anything similar to this?

Comment: You can use external actions to force some kind of poor man Glade integration into Pycharm.

Comment: I just found out Builder: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Builder but it's not yet ready.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for [Anjuta](http://anjuta.org/). It's an IDE with Glade built in.

Comment: It's a nice aproach but very buggy. It keeps crashing when I try to make a simple project.

Comment: It gives me this in python files: Error in template /usr/share/anjuta/templates/pygtk/src/main.py, line 3
 Could not resolve macro name: 'EMACS-MODELINE'

Answer (score 0):

Quickly uses [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/) as GUI designer. You can use Glade with PyCharm, too.

Comment: I know, but it's not integrated. In MonoDevelop you have the GUI designer on the IDE.  What would be nice would be a Gtk glade extension inside PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. :) Rather different from PyCharm, but [Stani's Python Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stani%27s_Python_Editor) is a great IDE for Python and ships with wxGlade (among other useful tools such as [Kiki](https://code.google.com/p/kiki-re/)).

It can be installed from Ubuntu repositories with:

```
sudo apt-get install spe
```

Comment: wxGlade is not GTK.

Comment: Oh, you're correct and my answer is slipped then. Anyways wx is cross platform and does fine with wxGlade. But you're right, this doesn't quite reach the requirements in the topic of the question. However, I don't know that does any other IDE either. Personally I use PyCharm as does the questioner and for GUI I'm using Boa Constructor, which while being abandoned and still having bugs here and there, I find a very suitable GUI builder. Boa Constructor writes direct wx code and doesn't create dependencies of its own.